# Why isn't my python script visual running as it should in power BI?

Tags: python, powerbi

Currently I am trying to get my python visualization to run. I know it is not about what is in my script but more about how the python visualization was set up. I installed python right to my command prompt. I have read that it has something to do with power Bi's end. I'm hoping this can be solved.

[image: This is the error that I am getting]

I have tried switching my language format so periods are commas because I've read that could be the issue. It did not solve the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to uncomment those lines.  They are there just to tell you what the variable name for your dataframe is and what columns it has.